# Bootstrap 4 dropdown works only once

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

i'm trying to make a dropdown with bootstrap 4. it works, but the problem is that it toggles only once. Also, I've tried solutions suggested on the site, but any of them could help me. Here's my code:

```
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share more details. Why is this tagged with jQuery, CSS, and [tag:responsive-design], but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with code here working fine I think you missing adding some bootstrap .js or .css

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: TY very much! I don't know what exactly was the problem(I use wordpress so I've connected bootstrap via php file), but i also had links to the scripts in my footer. MB I connected the script in the wrong place, mb the problem was with the version. Anyway, ty very much again!